# Fastreport not showing any content(text)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, fastreport

I had this issue where Fast-Report wasn't showing any content for my generated PDF. Even if it were static. I was looking for quite a while so I decided to document it for the internet archives.
Probably caused by copying a component
Again all the field are there and (probably) the data too

Comment: Nice post, but you need to write up a question that describes the problem you were having with the report, just like you would ask any other question here. Even questions you're going to self-answer need to adhere to the same standards as other questions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback this is the best i could do tho ;)

Comment: Um, no. There needs to be a *clear problem description* and *question*, just like any other question. See [ask] for the information that should be provided.

Comment: Like I said this is the best I could do you'd have to help me rephrase I already tried hence the edits

Answer (score 0):

The issue had to do with Fast-Report resetting all font color fields to null like following.

[image: Before]
The only thing you have to do is change color from null to the preferred color:

[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you try to use FR VCL report templates with FR FMX. In this case you should correct all colors in the report template or add FMX.ConverterFR3toFRFMX.pas unit in the uses list